# Data Structures C# Dictionary<int,user> and user has a property that is a list<numbers>

Tags: c#, object-oriented, hash-map

I am about to post a question to Stack Overflow about how to do a better job adding a number to the list inside the `User` class. But I feel if I refactored this I might solve my problem with coupling my data like this. So I am open to suggestions.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/0YtpnC)

```
public static void addOrUpdate(Dictionary<int, User> dic, int key, User user)
{
    //sets a new user data and just replaces it in the dictionary
    //var used = new User { ID = "id1", Name = "Harry" };
    var used = new User{ ID = "id3", Name = "Henry" ,AddressBook = new List<ContactNumber>(){new ContactNumber(3111),new ContactNumber(4444)}};

    if (dic.TryGetValue(key, out user))
    {
        // yay, value exists!
        dic[key] = used;

    }
    else
    {
        // darn, lets add the value 
        dic.Add(key, used);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll see there is a `ContainsKey` method that will work much better than that `TryGetValue` mess.

Comment: good suggestion Thank you, I was curious about that TryGetValue, something about that out in (key, out Value) seemed to be pointless. But hey it worked

Comment: Could you explain why you are creating a used variable and not using the passed in user? As of now you are just going to replace the passed in variable with the variable held in the Dictionary if it exists.

Comment: The idea was to identify the user based on the int Key in the Dictionary, or the name in the user class. and then update that users information. ( this is where I was having trouble). Would I copy the data to a new user was a thought and that is why i was passing the user to the update method. But understanding how to update just the list inside of user becomes a problem.

Answer (score 7):

You neither need `TryGetValue` nor `ContainsKey` if you don't care about the existence of the `User` in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which seems to be the case, because you want to either add  or update the `User` in the dict.

You can simply use the `Item` property setter to achieve this and after changing the method name to `AddOrUpdate` (based on the [NET naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)) your former method will look like so

```
public static void AddOrUpdate(Dictionary<int, User> dic, int key, User user)
{
    //sets a new user data and just replaces it in the dictionary
    //var used = new User { ID = "id1", Name = "Harry" };
    var used = new User{ ID = "id3", Name = "Henry" ,AddressBook = new List<ContactNumber>(){new ContactNumber(3111),new ContactNumber(4444)}};

    dic[key] = used;

}
```

This is because internally the [`Dictionary.Add()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/a7861da7aaa500fe.html) method calls `Insert()` with `true` for the add parameter like so

> ```
> public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
>     Insert(key, value, true);
> }
> ```

and the [`Item`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/49962975508e2d83.html) property looks like so

> ```
> public TValue this[TKey key] {
>     get {
>         int i = FindEntry(key);
>         if (i >= 0) return entries[i].value;
>         ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
>         return default(TValue);
>     }
>     set {
>         Insert(key, value, false);
>     }
> }
> ```

where the `add` parameter of the `Insert()` method call is `false`.

Comment: Does it mean that it is somehow possible to disable this line `ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();` in the getter and use the `return default(TValue);` instead if key not found? I often happen to `new` the `this` in a derived dictionary so that it doesn't throw on non-existing key.

Comment: @t3chb0t if you need to `get` a value based on a key you need to use `TryGetValue()` if you aren't sure if the key exists.

Comment: Sure thing ;-) but the default indexer is often more comfortable than the TryGetValue so I rather override the this and return a default value, usually when the value is a reference type. After seeing the source code in your answer I had hoped I can next time just disable the line that throws the exception ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t sure you can overide the indexer, but IMO thats not that good, because the expected behaviour of a dictionary is to throw if the key is not found. If you don't call the derived class `Dictionary` or something like this, you should be ok.

Comment: @t3chb0t - if you return `default(TValue)` for the getter you lose the information on whether the key was there and it's got the default value of the type or whether it simply wasn't there. In some cases that won't matter, but in the general case it is an important distinction.

Comment: @RobH There are situations where it's not allowed or resonable to have nulls so if my dictionary holds instances of something and returns null I'm cool with it. Similar to `SingleOrDefault`. It's just easier and shorter then to do some operations rather than having `TryGetValue` or `ContainsKey` everywhere. I call it a NullableDictionary. I'm glad that the dictionary isn't actually sealed. I call this _thinking-out-of-the-box_ ;-) Just because a dictionary's default getter throws an exception it doesn't mean it must always be that way.